# EF migration issue on one-to-one when related table references first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I have a 1:1 relationship between Companies and CompanyDemographics created like this:

```
public class Company
{
    public Company()
    {
        Contacts = new HashSet<Contact>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CompanyId")]
    public virtual CompanyDemographic Demographic { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
}

public class CompanyDemographic
{
    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("Company")]
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }

    public int EmployeeCount { get; set; }
}
```

The migration builds correctly and everything works.

I then added a reference from CompanyDemographic back to Company like this:

```
public class CompanyDemographic
{
    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("Company")]
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }

    public int EmployeeCount { get; set; }

    // ADDING THIS
    [ForeignKey("CurrentProvider")]
    public int CurrentProviderCompanyId { get; set; }
    public virtual Company CurrentProvider { get; set; }
}
```

When I go to add the migration, it looks like this:

```
public override void Up()
{
    DropForeignKey("dbo.Contacts", "CompanyId", "dbo.Companies");
    DropForeignKey("dbo.CompanyDemographics", "CompanyId", "dbo.Companies");
    DropPrimaryKey("dbo.Companies");
    AddColumn("dbo.CompanyDemographics", "CurrentProviderCompanyId", c => c.Int(nullable: false));
    AlterColumn("dbo.Companies", "CompanyId", c => c.Int(nullable: false));
    AddPrimaryKey("dbo.Companies", "CompanyId");
    CreateIndex("dbo.Companies", "CompanyId");
    CreateIndex("dbo.CompanyDemographics", "CurrentProviderCompanyId");
    AddForeignKey("dbo.CompanyDemographics", "CurrentProviderCompanyId", "dbo.Companies", "CompanyId", cascadeDelete: true);
    AddForeignKey("dbo.Contacts", "CompanyId", "dbo.Companies", "CompanyId", cascadeDelete: true);
    AddForeignKey("dbo.CompanyDemographics", "CompanyId", "dbo.Companies", "CompanyId");
}
```

It's trying to drop all the keys and rebuild. How do I avoid this?

Comment: Multiple references from same class can be an issue. I prefer fluent, but you can use [Inverse attribute](http://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/data-annotation-attributes/inverseproperty-attribute) as well. May need another CompanyDemographic  nav in Company.

Comment: Putting [InverseAttribute("Company")] on the Demographic property of Company (instead of ForeignKey) solved it! If you post it as an answer I'll mark it accepted.

Comment: Feel free to write your own answer. Glad it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting @Steve Greene comment into an answer:

---

Putting [InverseAttribute("Company")] on the Demographic property of Company (instead of ForeignKey) solved it!

```
[InverseAttribute("Company")]
public virtual CompanyDemographic Demographic { get; set; }
```